# Issues using .find

Tags: vba, excel

Hi and thanks for the help in advance.

I've made a small macro that takes my university courses from a raw format and converts it into a timetable of some description... It finds the day using .find, then the start and end times with .find, and then plots the data into the appropriate cells. Everything works wonderfully until it encounters a time that is 5 characters long e.g. 15.15; 12.25 14.35. It is happy with everything else. I imagine it is either an issue with how I declared the variables, or with the .find and after extensive troubleshooting I'm no closer to working it out. The issue crops up in the line starting stoptimerow or startrow depending on whether the 5 character time is in the start or end time of the course. Here's the offending code:

```
Sub MakeSchedule()

Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim tot As Long

Dim xday As Long
Dim xdetails As Long
Dim xstart As Long
Dim xstoptime As Long

Dim day As String
Dim details As String
Dim start As Single
Dim stoptime As Single
Dim daycol As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim stoptimerow As Long

xday = 3
xstart = 4
xstoptime = 5
xdetails = 6

Range("I1").Select
tot = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row - 1

For y = 1 To tot

day = ActiveCell.Offset(y, xday).Value
daycol = Range("B1:F1").Find(day, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column

start = ActiveCell.Offset(y, xstart).Value
stoptime = ActiveCell.Offset(y, xstoptime).Value
details = ActiveCell.Offset(y, xdetails).Value

startrow = Range("A1:A134").Find(start, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
stoptimerow = Range("A1:A134").Find(stoptime, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row

Range(Cells(startrow, daycol), Cells(stoptimerow, daycol)).Value = details


Next



End Sub
```

Comment: Could you try a time of `9.15` and see if that also produces an error? I think you almost certainly have a floating point precision issue

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! Unfortunately I just tried it and 9.15 also produces the error. Does that mean that it is NOT a floating point rounding error? The stoptime variable is defined as a Single; does that not handle floating point?

Comment: try formatting your cells as `time`

Comment: Hi jstola, I tried your solution, and it didn't help, but did result in excel giving very bizarre recurring decimal values to my variables... not sure why that happened...

Comment: I was expecting `9.15` to produce the error because it is a recurring decimal when expressed as part of a day - 0.3854166666666666... Floating point types like Single and Double can't precisely express a number like that and instead store a slightly imprecise approximation. This can cause issues when comparing the same number expressed in different types because each type could have a different approximation for some numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the Single data type with Find. Better use the Variant data type.

```
Sub FIND_Converts_Single_To_Double()
Dim sSingle As Single, dDouble As Double, a As Double
'Dim sSingle As Variant, dDouble As Double, a As Double
a = 22.23
sSingle = a
dDouble = a
Debug.Print sSingle = dDouble
Debug.Print dDouble, sSingle, CDbl(sSingle)
cells(1,1).value=a
Set c1 = Range("A1:A134").Find(sSingle, , LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set c2 = Range("A1:A134").Find(dDouble, , LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If c1 Is Nothing Then
 Debug.Print "Nothing"
Else
 Debug.Print c1
End If
Debug.Print c2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Sorted instantly! How should I know which data type to use in which scenario, and how can I easily tell that it is the data type that is causing any bug? Is there a link I should know about that could help explain this? Thanks once again.

Comment: 1) To know which data type to use, you can use Typename(activecell.Value), 2) Never use the Single Data Type. 3) Link : http://vb6reference.tomswebdesign.net/conversion.html